# Sum of exponential functions that vanishes

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions, exponential-function

I'm looking for a proof using elementary arguments of the following fact :

> Let $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_n$ and $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n$ be real
> numbers. One consider the function defined over $\mathbb R$ by : $$f: x\mapsto \sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k e^{a_kx}.$$
> If $f$ vanishes at $n$ distinct points then $\lambda_1=\cdots = \lambda_n=0$.

I know that the functions $x\mapsto e^{a_k x}$ with $k=1,\ldots,n$ are linearly independant but the condition isn't really the same here. This could be related to [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) but the calculus are ugly. So I'm trying to find an other way to proceed.

Any idea ?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/688606/42969

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.